# Which is correct in both meaning and grammar, 'argue' or 'to argue'?

Tags: grammar

Which is correct in both meaning and grammar, '*argue*' or '*to argue*'?

> 1. As a general rule, historians find it difficult to isolate events in history and **argue** their impact upon society. [*bare-infinitive parallelism*]
> 2. As a general rule, historians find it difficult to isolate events in history and **to argue** their impact upon society. [*to-infinitive parallelism*]

Is there no difference in meaning between the two sentences?

In my opinion,

1. to (isolate ... and argue ...) : subsequent acts
2. (to isolate ...) and (to argue ...) : separate acts

Thus, I think that '*argue*' is a logically correct expression.

Comment: There's no difference in meaning, and no "logic" involved in the usage, or "correctness" for either choice. Yours is just a typical context where a repeated word (such as ***to***) can be omitted in parallel constructions (but it doesn't *have* to be omitted).

Answer (score 1):

When repeating parallel structures it's often permissible to omit repeated words, without changing the meaning in any way.

> When driving in the UK, American drivers must learn **to** stay to the left, **(to)** follow all road signs, and **(to)** watch out for cross-traffic.
>
> In an emergency **keep** calm, **(keep)** organized, and **(keep)** alert.

Retaining the repeating words can add emphasis to that specific action:

> The only way to get control of your life is to **turn off** the phone, **turn off** the TV, **turn off** the computer -- and **turn on** to what's happening around you in the real world.